# Iterating a combined json object

Tags: php, jquery

I have this php code tat gets data from mysql and combines into into one big json object and passes it to the view via ajax get

```
$user_id = $this->ion_auth->get_user_id();
//Get Stats
$addresses = $this->db->query("select count(*) as addresses from addressbook where user_id = '$user_id'")->row()->addresses;
$individual = $this->db->query("select count(*) as individual from addressbook where user_id = '$user_id' and category='individual'")->row()->individual;
$business = $this->db->query("select count(*) as business from addressbook where user_id = '$user_id' and category = 'business'")->row()->business;
$kount = $this->db->query("select count(*) as kount from addressbook where user_id = '$user_id'")->row()->kount;
$latest = $this->db->query("select * from addressbook where user_id = '$user_id' limit 5")->result_array();
        //Latest Records
$bundle = json_encode([$addresses, $individual, $business, $kount, $latest]);
print_r($bundle);
```

This is my jquery code

```
$.get(window.get_url, function( data ) {
var jd = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
console.log(jd);

var addresses = jd[0];
var individual = jd[1];
var business = jd[2];

var latest = jd[4];

$.each(latest, function(i, item) {
 $.each(item, function(x, y) {
     $(".latest").html("<a href='#' class='list-group-item list-group-item-action'><i class='icon-circle mr-3'></i>"+item.names+"</a>");
});
});

});
```

The data being returned looks like this

> ["5","2","3","5",[{"id":"8","category":"individual","names":"xsjjhdjh","telephone":"0800439005","email":"info@myer.com","description":"ddgdjh","last_updated":"1571756884","user_id":"1"},{"id":"9","category":"individual","names":"jhjhjh","telephone":"0800439005g","email":"info@myer.comvgv","description":"fgffg","last_updated":"1571757334","user_id":"1"},{"id":"10","category":"business","names":"dss","telephone":"0800439005e","email":"info@myer.come","description":"ddff","last_updated":"1571757569","user_id":"1"},{"id":"11","category":"business","names":"dss","telephone":"6w3636","email":"me@you.,com","description":"ddff","last_updated":"1571758012","user_id":"1"},{"id":"12","category":"business","names":"dss","telephone":"777878","email":"she@her.com","description":"ddff","last_updated":"1571758023","user_id":"1"}]]

I want to display the names in a widget like

```
$(".latest").html("<a href='#' class='list-group-item list-group-item-action'><i class='icon-circle mr-3'></i>"+item.names+"</a>");
```

but this is only giving the last name and not all names?.

here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6hpuacnm/

How can i display all the names instead of just the last one?.

Comment: Your inner .each loop isn't doing anything useful (x and y don't seem to be used).

Comment: Also, each time you set the content of $(".latest"), you're overwriting the previous content.

Comment: Oh dear, i was suppossed to append not html!

Comment: But even after i use append, and use setinterval, it shall just be appending and not replacing

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this. First i empty the `.latest` and `append` the new content

```
var latest = jd[4];
$(".latest").empty();

$.each(latest, function(i, item) {
$(".latest").append("<a href='#' class='list-group-item list-group-item-action'><i class='icon-circle mr-3'></i>"+item.names+"</a>");
});
```